# DOM is not updated by pushing object into the Array,database is updated after pushing the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have verified data in the  database, it is getting updated, but DOM is not getting updated.

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="aReview in reviewList">    
    ....
    ....
   </li>
 </ul>
<script>
if(globalMethods.stringValidation($scope.reviewList))
{
   $scope.reviewList.push(optData);
}
else
{
   $scope.reviewList=[];
   $scope.reviewList.push(optData);
}
</script>
```

Comment: How are you triggering the method that adds the data to the database? You may need to include a [$scope.apply](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply%28%29) call.

Comment: You'll have to provide more code in order to see what's happening. Where is optData coming from? Are you passing the reviewList array to whatever uploads it to your database, or is it a different datasource? Can we see the controller where the reviewList array is initialized, then populated in this context?

Comment: Updated Readability.

Comment: You'll have to provide more code in order to see what's happening. Where is optData coming from? 

Ans) optData is a object. i have checked the optData by debugging

Are you passing the reviewList array to whatever uploads it to your database, 
Ans)Yes
or is it a different datasource?
Ans)No
 Can we see the controller where the reviewList array is initialized, then populated in this context?
 
Ans)optdata is directly declared.i have verified optdata again again

Comment: I sometimes have this issue, specially when reordering an array of objects. My solution is within the function to create a temporary array variable, add them in order to that, and then set the array as the temp array. Usually this updates the DOM. (I don't use angular though, but have encountered this problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third party libraries to manipulate your data, angular may not be aware of changes to data. To get angular to recheck things, you have to mannually invoke $scope.$apply() after manipulating your data